# How can i make a for loop with if else and make the good return type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop

i would like to resolve a problem,

i've done this code and i have this output

```
found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]       for (data <- category(i)) {
```

i have to return : `(List[String], (List[String], (List[String])`

i choose to use the filter method for to realise a compact code. 
i don't understand why it doesn't work. Why the code doesn't return a bool but a Unit.

I would like this method to return true if at least 1 element of the list starts with x otherwise the method must return false.

Thanks

```
def classifiedColumns(columnNames: List[String]): (List[Column], List[Column], List[Column]) = {
    val category = List(
      List("t01", "t03", "t11", "t1801", "t1803"), // 1
      List("t05", "t1805"), // 2
      List("t02", "t04", "t06", "t07", "t08", "t09", "t10", "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t16", "t18")) // 3

    def get_info(x: String, i: Int, category: List[List[String]]): Boolean = {
      for (data <- category(i)) {
        if (data.startsWith(x)) true
        else false
      }
    }

    (columnNames.filter(x => get_info(x, 1, category)).map(column),
      columnNames.filter(x => get_info(x, 2, category)).map(column),
      columnNames.filter(x => get_info(x, 3,  category)).map(column))
  }

classifiedColumns(List("t0201", "t0408", "t0600084"))
```

Comment: You can't return implicitly from a for loop. It's not clear what get_info is expected to do. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `for` does not behave as you expect. You're using this for-comprehension:

```
for (data <- category(i)) {
  if (data.startsWith(x)) true
  else false
}
```

This expression "desugars" into (i.e. is shorthand for):

```
category(i).foreach(data => {
  if (data.startsWith(x)) true
  else false
})
```

`foreach` returns `Unit`, and therefore the type of this expression (and the type returned from your `get_info` method, this being the body of the method) is `Unit`.

It's unclear what you expect to be returned here, I'm assuming you want the method to return `true` if *any* of the elements in `category(i)` start with `x`. If so, you can implement it as follows:

```
category(i).exists(_.startsWith(x))
```

Which returns a `Boolean`, as expected.

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename